# LINQ Entity Reusable query. Change from based on parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the linq query below. I have several log tables, all with the same structure so I'd like to reuse the queries but change the from section based on a passed string parameter. My initial thought was to create a method that would look at the parameter and return the correct DBContext. However, it doesn't appear to be that simple.

So an example if I pass a parameter "WO" then through my method it should return DBContext.wologs. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
from l in **this.DBContext.wologs** //This part should be adjusted dynamically
where l.parentid == Convert.ToInt32(Encryption.Decrypt(primaryKey))
orderby l.transactiondate
select new
       {
        chartdate = l.transactiondate,
        tabledate = l.transactiondate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"),
        oldvalue = l.oldvalue ?? "",
        newvalue = l.newvalue ?? "",
        l.field,
        l.tableaction
       }
```

Comment: At a minimum, your different log tables would need to share a common base class or interface - how else would you get compile time access to `l.parentid`?

Comment: They all have the same structure but I guess that's where I'm confused in understanding how recast or assign the correct DBContext. I've setup an interface that contains the fields they all share and currently am trying to cast the correct DBContext to this interface based on an if statement. It's producing an error that tells me it's not seeing the correct entity.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this via Generic Repository design [Example](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/generic-repository-pattern-csharp-mvc/#google_vignette).

Have a method named `Get<T>(func where)`
Based on input parameter, switch your code to concrete type.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve dynamic selection of the DBContext based on a passed string parameter by using reflection and the DbContext class. Here's a general outline of how you can do it:

Create a method that takes the table name as a string parameter.
Inside the method, use reflection to dynamically access the DbContext property that corresponds to the table name.
Here's some sample code illustrating this approach:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetLogData(string tableName, int primaryKey)
{
    // Get the DbContext property using reflection
    var dbContextProperty = this.DBContext.GetType().GetProperty(tableName);

    if (dbContextProperty == null)
    {
        // Handle the case where the table name doesn't match any DbContext property
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid table name");
    }

    // Get the DbSet property from the DbContext property
    var dbSetProperty = dbContextProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("DbSetProperty");

    if (dbSetProperty == null)
    {
        // Handle the case where the DbSet property is not found
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid table name");
    }

    // Create an instance of the DbSet
    var dbSet = dbSetProperty.GetValue(dbContextProperty.GetValue(this.DBContext));

    // Use LINQ to query the data
    var query = from l in (IQueryable<object>)dbSet
                where (int)l.GetType().GetProperty("parentid").GetValue(l) == primaryKey
                orderby (DateTime)l.GetType().GetProperty("transactiondate").GetValue(l)
                select new
                {
                    chartdate = (DateTime)l.GetType().GetProperty("transactiondate").GetValue(l),
                    tabledate = ((DateTime)l.GetType().GetProperty("transactiondate").GetValue(l)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"),
                    oldvalue = (string)l.GetType().GetProperty("oldvalue").GetValue(l) ?? "",
                    newvalue = (string)l.GetType().GetProperty("newvalue").GetValue(l) ?? "",
                    field = (string)l.GetType().GetProperty("field").GetValue(l),
                    tableaction = (string)l.GetType().GetProperty("tableaction").GetValue(l)
                };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

In this code:

tableName is the parameter that specifies which table you want to query.
Reflection is used to access the DbContext property that corresponds to the table name.
Then, reflection is used again to access the DbSet property within the DbContext property.
Finally, LINQ is used to query the data from the dynamically selected DbSet.
Please adapt this code to your specific scenario, including property names and types used in your DbContext and DbSet classes. Additionally, you may want to consider error handling for cases where the table name or DbSet property is not found.